# Checking record before update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Goal:** To check if a record has already been updated and either allow or not allow the record to be updated if it already has been.

This is in case a buyer is on a page that doesn't have updated information and attempts to cancel an order once it's already been completed.

I have the following code, which works but also doesn't work correctly:

```
private

    def prevent_order_update
      @order = Order.find(params[:id])
      if ( @order.order_status[2] || @order.order_status[3] ) 
        redirect_to @order, notice: "Your request status for Order:#{@order.id} has already been updated."
      end
    end
```

**with:**

```
  before_action :prevent_order_update, :only => [:update]
```

This works, but also "works" if the `:order_status` is `1`, which is shouldn't.

I only want a block in the update IF the order status is anything but `1`.

The order status is from a model enum of 1,2,3.

**I have also tried using:**

`if ( @order.order_status[2] || @order.order_status[3] ) && @order.order_status_previously_changed?`

which completely blocks the `prevent_order_update` from working all together.

**And:**

`( @order.order_status[2] || @order.order_status[3] ) != @order.order_status[1]`

Which then blocks my update method all together and still gives me the `prevent_order_update` method notice when the order status is `1`

Comment: Would you share the output of `@order.order_status` ?

Comment: `enum order_status: { created: 1, charged: 2, canceled: 3 }`

Comment: Is it rails enum right?

Comment: Do you use db enum or rails enum?

Comment: It is rails enum

Comment: I shared a solution. Would you test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@order.order_status` is corresponding to string when it comes to rails enums. 
In your case, say `@order.order_status` is `charged`. When you execute `@order.order_status[2]` it actually produces `a` which is the third item of `charged` string. In this case the comparison always returns true.
So try the following code:

```rb
    def prevent_order_update
      @order = Order.find(params[:id])
      if ( @order.charged? || @order.canceled? ) 
        redirect_to @order, notice: "Your request status for Order:#{@order.id} has already been updated."
      end
    end
```

Comment: I use this for my @user model but never thought to try it elsewhere lmao.  thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use aasm gem, so that you no need any before_action. You can solve it in model level using aasm transitions

https://github.com/aasm/aasm